# Background color of text, including overflow

Tags: microsoft-excel, colors, microsoft-excel-2016

I have some cells with text, that overflows into the next column.
Now I want to color the background of the text.

In Excel I can set the background color of the **cell**, but is there a way to set the background color of the **text**, including the overflowing part?

[image]

In the above picture, I want the the whole "LONG_TEXT" in the same background color.

Comment: Since Excel cell could contain max of 255 Characters so overlapping can't be captured by formula. In that  case better you observe that after how many  characters the Text overlaps the cell width and use the LEN function accordingly to test them to highlight like, `=Len($A1)>10`.

Answer (score 2):

No, the Excel font object doesn't possess a background color property. It is the color of the cells, as you have noted, that is the background for general text on a worksheet.

Perhaps you could try if a *Textbox* would be useful for you. Maybe not as a general solution for any text, because it requires extra work, but to be used occasionally. A Textbox can have its own background color, and it can be set to autofit - resize to fit the text as you edit.

A textbox "floats" above the grid of a worksheet as you can see from the sample image:

[image]

You can add a TextBox to the worksheet from the ribbon: **Add** - **Text group** - **Textbox**.

Some shapes can also hold text, just like the Textboxes.